# как пользователь может ввести время в с#?

Tags: c#, datetime

Возникла необходимость дать пользователю возможность ввести время и сохранить его куда-нибудь в переменную, скорее всего необходимо использовать структуру DateTime, но не совсем понятно как можно все это реализовать.
По ходу программы нужно будет сравнивать несколько переменных, их продолжительность.

Comment: `var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`? Форматы можно посмотреть здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0

Comment: Еще есть `TimeSpan`. Он немного отличается и если время - это просто промежуток, не имеющий отношения к датам, то этот вариант подойдет лучше. [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222930/373567) я работал с временем.

Comment: Ребят, а ответ никто не хочет написать?

Comment: Приложение у вас какого типа: консольное, гуевое, веб? Вот, например, ввод в [консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655754/184217)

Comment: Ваш вопрос необходимо уточнить т.к. вы не указали какое приложение вы используете. В случае использования windows form ответ будет один, а в случае с консольным приложением - другой.